# Writing a .NET (C#) dll for a Delphi App

Tags: c#, delphi

A friend asked me about writing a dll in C# for a delphi app. He wants to communicate with it using this function decleration:

```
function OpenAddOnFile(const mafCode: PWideChar; const mafFilePath: PWideChar;
                   const mafVersion: PWideChar): Pointer; stdcall;
```

The problem I have is translating it to C#. PWideChar isnt available etc... I've tried it like that:

```
public Pointer OpenAddOnFile(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string mafcode,     
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string maffilepath,  
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string mafversion
)
```

But its not working for now :)

Further more how can I return a Pointer to my form in C#?

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:\

He gave me this additional code:
I asked him for the function call, he gave me this info:

```
unit unAddOn;

interface

uses
   Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
   System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
   Vcl.ComCtrls;

function LoadAddOnFile(aPath: String; aVersion: String; var aFilePath: String;
                       var aCode: String): Boolean;

const
    AddOnExt: String = '.maf';

implementation

function LoadAddOnFile(aPath: String; aVersion: String; var aFilePath: String;
                   var aCode: String): Boolean;
type
   TOpenAddOnFile = function(const mafCode: PWideChar; const mafFilePath: PWideChar;
                        const mafVersion: PWideChar): Pointer; stdcall;
   TCloseAddOnFile = procedure(var mafCode: PWideChar; var mafFilePath: PWideChar;
                          var mafQuitPopUp: PWideChar); stdcall;
var
   CloseAddOnFile: TCloseAddOnFile;
   OpenAddOnFile: TOpenAddOnFile;
   AddOnMainForm: TForm;
   AddOnHandle: THandle;
   mafQuitPopUp: PWideChar;
   mafFilePath: PWideChar;
   mafVersion: PWideChar;
   mafCode: PWideChar;
begin
   Result := True;
   mafQuitPopUp := PWideChar(EmptyStr);
   mafFilePath  := PWideChar(aFilePath);
   mafCode      := PWideChar(aCode);
   mafVersion   := PWideChar(aVersion);

   try
   AddOnHandle := LoadLibrary(PWideChar(aPath));
if (AddOnHandle <> 0) then
begin
  @OpenAddOnFile  := GetProcAddress(AddOnHandle, 'OpenAddOnFile');
  @CloseAddOnFile := GetProcAddress(AddOnHandle, 'CloseAddOnFile');

  if (@OpenAddOnFile <> nil) then
  begin
    AddOnMainForm := OpenAddOnFile(mafCode, mafFilePath, mafVersion);
    AddOnMainForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
    AddOnMainForm.ShowModal;
    if (@CloseAddOnFile <> nil) then
    begin
      CloseAddOnFile(mafCode, mafFilePath, mafQuitPopUp);
    end;
    FreeAndNil(AddOnMainForm);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;

if not (mafQuitPopUp = PWideChar(EmptyStr)) then
begin
  ShowMessage(mafQuitPopUp);
end;
aFilePath := String(mafFilePath);
aCode := String(mafCode);
except
Result := False;
end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Yes you can return a pointer in C#

Comment: So, how are you loading a C# DLL from Delphi. Is it native Win32 Delphi, or Delphi.net? And there is no `Pointer` in C#. There is `IntPtr`. And what is the return value? What is the C# app meant to return? And do the parameters point to modifiable buffers? Basically your question is utterly lacking in detail needed to answer it.

Comment: And another question. What does "it's not working mean"? Your dev tools give you error messages that contain detail. Why would you not pass on that information. Are you trying to make it hard for us?!

Comment: Its Native Delphi and afaik my friend wants to have a return pointer pointing to my form I genererated in my dll. It just gives no message, I would have posted that :D

Comment: How are you going to convert a C# form into a pointer? What is the Delphi app going to do with it? How are you going to turn a C# DLL into something that can export unmanaged functions? You have many many hurdles to cross before you can even consider the issues in this question.

Comment: I updated the post above... ;) In this sitiuation, he just wants to show the form. But yeah, I know, there might some problems with the compability between c# and vcl-forms ;)

Comment: @user985798 The details of this question aside: In general, try to consider your questions from the perspective of someone who has absolutely none of the context that you do about the problem. Summarising the problem as "it's not working" doesn't communicate *anything* - if it was working, you wouldn't be here. What do you expect to happen? What *actually* happens? Is an exception thrown? Does the process crash? What do any error messages say?

Comment: It's reasonable to omit a detail like native vs. managed until you're asked for it (because you might not initially realise that it's relevant) but provide *as much* of what you *do* know as you can, because otherwise people have to spend time digging out the basic symptoms (which you're in the position to provide up front) before they can get around to even diagnosing the problem, let alone helping you with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are attempting is impossible. You cannot implement a Delphi form in C#. The code that you posted treats the pointer returned by the DLL function as a Delphi form. The only thing that can implement a Delphi form is code compiled by Delphi.

What's more, your code is not even valid if the DLL is implemented in Delphi. That's because the `TForm` class in the host executable is not the same as the `TForm` class in the DLL. In order to do what you are attempting to do, with a Delphi DLL, you'd need to pass interfaces across the module boundary.

The bottom line is that your current design for this add-on architecture can never work. You need to go right back to the drawing board and start again.

Comment: Okay, I will tell him that. So, is it possible to do it without the form pointer returned, for example with no return value or just a integer, leaving out the pointers? The delphi code is not my problem :)

Comment: Well, if you move the code that shows the form into the DLL, then yes it's possible. You'll still need to find a way to create an unmanaged export from your C# DLL. For example Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports.

Comment: Or, you can load the .NET runtime into the Delphi application and host the .NET assemblies directly. You can then talk to the .NET objects through the COM interop layer that Delphi has, using "OleVariant" to wrap .NET objects. It's a bit of work, but it can be done. It's still not going to be a TForm in any way or form, but you can definitely load up .NET objects and call methods on them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Or you can do it via COM. Yes there are lots of ways. But right off the bat a C# DLL does not support being loaded with LoadLibrary from a native host.

Answer (score 1):

You could, perhaps, implement it slightly differently with a smallish change to the calling routines in Delphi.

If you were to use the [UnmanagedExports](https://nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) (availabe as a Nuget package) as mentioned by David you could get the OpenAddonFile call to return an **interface** rather than a form. The interface could implement ShowModal and Position.
CloseAddonFile could return an appropriate value as normal. Doesn't matter then whether it's a form a console app or anything else so long as you can call ShowModal on it.

I have found the UnmanagedExports to be very good so long as you remember to only return int / void types from the methods and any strings are returned as var / out parameters.